# javascript, nodejs await promised array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, async-await

I have a problem with promised array:
I'm calling inside my switch a function which is loading an array from API
Example:

```
let sorted = []
let limit = 10
async function loadPage(slcLimit) {
    let i
    let filter = document.getElementById("show-filter").value

    if (sorted.length == 0) {
        switch (filter) {
            case "1":
                let realWoolPromiseAsc = await Promise.resolve(realWool(pagingPouches))
                    .then((realWoolArr) => {
                        sorted = realWoolArr.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a.realWool) - parseFloat(b.realWool));
                        return sorted
                    })
                break;
            case "2":
                let realWoolPromiseDesc = await Promise.resolve(realWool(pagingPouches))
                    .then((realWoolArr) => {
                        sorted = realWoolArr.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(b.realWool) - parseFloat(a.realWool));
                        return sorted
                    })
                break;
        }
    }


        for (i = startingLimit; i < (startingLimit + limit); i++) {
            console.log(sorted[i].ID + " - " + sorted[i].price)
        }
}
```

Real wool function

```
window.realWool = async function realWool(pouchArr) {
    let divider = 1000000000000000000n;
    let realWoolArray = []
    pouchArr.forEach(async pouch => {
        let availAmount = await pouchContract.amountAvailable(pouch.pouchID)
        availAmount = Number(BigInt(availAmount.toString()) * 100n / divider) / 100
        availAmount = Math.floor(availAmount * 100) / 100
        let rWool = pouch.pouchWool - availAmount
        realWoolArray.push({pouchID: pouch.pouchID, realWool: rWool, pouchTime: pouch.pouchTime})
        //document.getElementById("lockedText" + pouch.pouchID).innerHTML = "Real WOOL: <span class='black'>" + rWool + "</span>"
    });
    return realWoolArray
}
```

I need to use the **sorting** array inside my for loop but I'm getting undefined. I understand I need to use await or a then block I just have no clue how to use that.

Thank you!

I've used a **timeout**, but it is not optimal since sometimes the function just return an array of 5 objects and sometimes a hundreds of objects (depends on filters)

```
setTimeout(() => {
        for (i = startingLimit; i < (startingLimit + limit); i++) {
            console.log(sorted[i].ID + " - " + sorted[i].price)
        }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: It's going to be hard to help without a [mre]. Can you update your question to include one? See [ask].

Comment: I've edited it. Hope this is better.

Comment: Your `loadPage` function does not return anything, so it resolves to `undefined`. Is that intended?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen this is still not the whole function. It is working with the timeout but it is not the best solution.

Comment: Why do you use `Promise.resolve`? What is `realWool`, is it even asynchronous? Does it return a promise?

Comment: What's he point of the `let realWoolPromiseAsc = ` (and `…Desc`) declarations? You're not using those variables anywhere.

Comment: @Bergi It literally doesnt matter. This is not a full function this is just a small block of code. It is returning a promise and it has to be asynchronous. My problem is: I don't want to use TIMEOUT what should I use instead of timeout? 
Thats my question and I don't know the answer.

Comment: @nodejs_newbie You don't need a timeout or anything. Your code uses an `await`, which means it pauses in the `switch`/`case` and executes the `for` loop only afterwards. If that doesn't work, there is a problem with your `realWool` function.

Comment: @Bergi then please explain why it is working with the timeout and without timeout im getting `undefined` -> the realwool function is getting data from Ethereum contract and just returning an array of objects.

Comment: @nodejs_newbie If it doesn't work, show us the `realWool` function implementation. I'm pretty sure it doesn't return an array.

Comment: @Bergi it is working with timeout so imo it is returning an array. I will post the realWool function to the first question.

Comment: Ah, it's returning (a promise for) an array, but that array is empty (until later, which is why you see the full array in the `setTimeout` callback). The problem is that [you cannot use `forEach` with async functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37576685/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here: `pouchArr.forEach(async pouch => {...})`
this is a fire and forget situation. `forEach` will start all the tasks at once and then as soon as all have started, forEach is done and your code goes to the next command `return realWoolArray` before even the first entry has been added.

Then in `loadPage` your sort will sort a (currently) empty array, ... and when all your synchronous code is done, and the Promises start to resolve, your code pushes the items all the way into the `sort` array.

```
window.realWool = async function realWool(pouchArr) {
    const divider = 1000000000000000000n;
    return Promise.all(
      pouchArr.map(async (pouch) => {
        let availAmount = await pouchContract.amountAvailable(pouch.pouchID)
        availAmount = Number(BigInt(availAmount.toString()) * 100n / divider) / 100;

        return {
          pouchID: pouch.pouchID, 
          realWool: pouch.pouchWool - availAmount, 
          pouchTime: pouch.pouchTime
        }
      })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return from the `then` block.

And spell `length` correctly.

You do not need to set the module scoped `sorting` in the `then` block either.

```
     let promisedArray = await Promise.resolve(myFunction())
     .then((realArray) => {
         sorting = realArray.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a.price) - parseFloat(b.price));
        
         return sorting // <-- return to awaited value
      })

      for (let i = 0; i < promisedArray.length; i++) { <-- check spelling
         console.log(promisedArray[i]) //returns the value I need
        }
```

You do not need `await Promise.resolve` either, just await `realWool`.

Comment: It will never get to that point, because the sort routine in the then block will throw.

Comment: Unfortuntately it is still not working for me and I'm getting an undefined. I will edit the question with the real block of code maybe it will be more helpful. This was a dummy block of code - one of the reasons why my spelling was bad.

Comment: @nodejs_newbie Put a log statement in after your api call returns, in the then statement, to ensure you are getting your data.

Comment: @StevenSpungin if I use the timeout Im getting the data.

Answer (score 0):

The array `sorted` that you use in the `loadPage` function is a global variable, which means that all invocations of `loadPage` (I assume that each incoming request causes one invocation) will access the same array concurrently. This cannot lead to correct (or even predictable) results.

Put the `let sorted = []` inside the function body to make it local. And the function must return something, for example `return realWoolPromiseAsc`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with my problem at all. Again: My block of code is fully WORKING I just don't want to use TIMEOUT and I assuem I could use AWAIT or something similar --- I just don't know how to do it.

I dont want to use timeout because: sometimes my api returns 5 objects, sometimes 5000...